# Passing reference to class constructor, "provides no initializer for"

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass a class reference to a field, but I get the error "'mazeGenerator::maze' references must be initialized".

I tried initializing 'maze' above the class constructor.

Why is this happening?

```
class mazeGenerator {
public:
    Maze& maze;

    mazeGenerator(Maze& mazeObj) {
        maze=mazeObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn the difference between _initialization_ and _assignment_. Your code is doing the latter.

Comment: Exactly what it says.   A reference must be initialised (made to reference something) as it is created.    The assignment `maze = mazeObj` assigns the value of the object referenced by `maze` the value of `mazeObj`.   In classes, a reference member can only be initialised as the object is constructed, which is done in the constructor initialiser list `mazeGenerator(Maze &mazeObj) : maze(mazeObj) {}`.    That ASSUMES the passed `mazeObj` was constructed in other code AND will continue to exist for as long as the `mazeGenerator` object does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *must* initialize data members of reference type with a member initializer list, like this:

```
mazeGenerator(Maze& mazeObj) : maze(mazeObj) {}
```

This is also the case with `const` data members.

Note that putting the declaration of the data member above the constructor doesn't actually make any difference; it could be declared below as well.

Also, your data members (whether they are of reference type or not), should be `private` to the class.